# Where can I find the highest CR Vampire ever in an official adventure module?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, monsters, dnd-3e, published-adventures

Where can I find the highest-CR pre-built Vampire opponent in all of Dungeon & Dragons 3e and 3.5 (as that is my favored system) or Pathfinder?

I am looking for official adventure modules and campaign settings that have pre-generated enemies, and that have a single vampire higher than the one written for *Heart of Nightfang Spire,* which is CR 15.

Comment: As Vampire is a template in 3.0/3.5/PF, you could just take stats for a very powerful monster or person (Elminster, Aroden, the Terrasque, Mordenkainen, Drizzt, etc) and add the Vampire template.  Boom, most ridiculous vampire ever.  (Elminster and Mordenkainen probably work better as liches, though!)

Comment: Also, levels don't mean the same thing in every edition of D&D; something that's 20th level in one edition may actually be *weaker* than something that's 15th level in another.

Comment: @gatherer8t8 I am not looking for what I could edit into a powerful vampire I am looking for an already written cannon adventure module that has one in it as an encounter write up

Comment: Because magic is so much more important than might in 3.X, mid level 'spellcaster' vampires will be vastly more powerful than even exceedingly high level 'martial' ones, if the martial ones aren't built very carefully, despite having a much lower listed CR.  Basically, CR is broken, are you sure it's the metric you want?

Answer (score 11):

*Quick Silver Hourglass* is an epic 3.5 adventure in [Dungeon Magazine Issue 123](http://paizo.com/products/btpy7xte?Dungeon-Issue-123) by [Anson Caralya](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Works_by_Anson_Caralya).   It has in it the vampire sorcerer Baucojin, known as the "Crimson Eclipse", CR 31 vampire (male human vampire sorcerer 29), and member of the [Union of Eclipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_of_Eclipses)!

An [actual play](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?144696-The-Quicksilver-Hourglass-in-play-*spoilers*) gives a good overview of the adventure.

Answer (score 8):

In [*Shadows of Gallowspire*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8mgb?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-48-Shadows-of-Gallowspire), part 6 of the *Pathfinder* adventure path Carrion Crown, there appears a [vampire human antipaladin 17](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/unique-monsters/cr-19/human-vampire-antipaladin-17), making it CR 19. Several other mid-level vampires are listed on the Web page [Unique Monsters](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/unique-monsters) if high-powered minions are needed.

Comment: nice thanks! I will defiantly check that out.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from the 3.5 Monster Manual's sample Elite Vampire (CR 15), the highest CR pre-generated vampire I could find for 3.5 is *Expedition to Castle Ravenloft*'s **Count Strahd Von Zarovich** which is also CR 15. Despite him having the same CR as the one to which you are referring from *Heart of Nightfang Spire*, Strahd has the benefit of being balanced specifically for 3.5 so if that is the system you're playing, then no conversions are necessary. Additionally, Strahd is essentially just a level 10 Human Necromancer with the Vampire template added on, so if you wanted to increase his difficulty, merely give him more levels of Necromancer.

Comment: Thank you for your time spent in research, I have seen that the limit to pre-generated vampires seems to be CR 15, as for Count Strahd Von Zarovich being not as powerful or strong as The write up from Heart of Nightfang Spire I will have to just use that one for my conversion; I hope I can find another one so I will keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late, but City of the Spider Queen (WotC ) has a couple of CR16 vampires:

-Jhorganni, Female drider vampire: Clr7; CR16, pg.152

-Maas, Vampire Assassin: Male drow vampire Mnk4/Rog4/Asn5; CR16, pg.155